# Filter all days between a time range

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter, subset

I have a data frame like below:

```
entry_no      id            time
_________     ___           _____
1              1        2016-09-01 09:30:09
2              2        2016-09-02 10:36:18
3              1        2016-09-01 12:27:27
4              3        2016-09-03 10:24:30
5              1        2016-09-01 12:35:39
6              3        2016-09-06 10:19:45
```

From this I want to filter the entries which occurs between the time 9 am to 10 am for every day.I know  for one day I can use something like:

```
results=filter(df,time>='2016-09-01 09:00:00' && time<='2016-09-01 10:00:00')
```

but to filter out the results for every day of the month.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Also don't use `&&` unless you really want to do comparison with only the first element of `df$time`. `&` is the full vectorised `AND`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could achieve it with a bit of simple formatting:

```
dat$hms <- format(as.POSIXct(dat$time), "%H:%M:%S")
dat[dat$hms >= "09:00:00" & dat$hms <= "10:00:00",]

#  entry_no id                time      hms
#1        1  1 2016-09-01 09:30:09 09:30:09
```

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest using `lubridate` package.

```
library(lubridate)

date.range <- interval(as.POSIXct("2016-09-01 09:00:00"), #lower bound
                       as.POSIXct("2016-09-01 10:00:00")  #upper bound
                       ) 

filtered.results <- df[df$time %within% date.range,]
```

You may need to check the class of `time` variable and apply some changes before getting the results:

```
df$time <- as.POSIXct(df$time)
```

Comment: answer works with `lubridate::interval()` as per lubridate 1.7.9.9000