# Subset rows according to a range of time (incl. minutes)

Tags: r, datetime, time, dplyr, lubridate

My question is basically a follow-up on the question previously raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420155/subset-rows-according-to-a-range-of-time) by user Wet Feet:

This is the modified dataset:

```
      date_time loc_id node  energy   kgco2 
1 2009-02-27 00:11:08     87  103 0.00000 0.00000 
2 2009-02-27 01:05:05     87  103 7.00000 3.75900 
3 2009-02-27 02:05:05     87  103 6.40039 3.43701 
4 2009-02-28 02:10:05     87  103 4.79883 2.57697 
5 2009-02-28 04:05:05     87  103 4.10156 2.20254 
6 2009-02-28 05:05:05     87  103 2.59961 1.39599
7 2009-03-01 03:20:05     87  103 2.59961 1.39599
```

I am trying to get only those rows which fall within a specific time interval, e.g. 02:05:00 to 03:30:00.

```
3 2009-02-27 02:05:05     87  103 6.40039 3.43701 
4 2009-02-28 02:10:05     87  103 4.79883 2.57697
7 2009-03-01 03:20:05     87  103 2.59961 1.39599
```

Applying the solution in the linked question (`hour` from the `lubridate` package), however, doesn't suffice since I also have to consider the minutes of my interval. I could use the `interval` function from the `lubridate` package to include minutes, but since my dataframe covers different dates, it wouldn't help.

I am particularly curious whether there is any solution allowing to make use of `dplyr` 's `filter` verb. Or is using the `xts` package the only way forward?

Comment: I think you're going to have to use `minutes` with some `or`'s and `and`'s: `filter((hour(date_time) == 2 & minutes(date_time) >= 5) | (hour(date_time) == 3 & minutes(date_time) <= 30))`

Comment: Relevant, possibly a duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251861/filter-all-days-between-a-time-range-in-r/44251952

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below, for each row I calculate the number of seconds since midnight and check whether that value is within the time range in your question, also converted to seconds since midnight. I've included the code to set up the data with a datetime format (and UTC time zone) since the data sample wasn't provided in reproducible form.

**1. Set up the data frame**

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

dat = read.table(text="date_time time loc_id node  energy   kgco2 
                 1 2009-02-27 00:11:08     87  103 0.00000 0.00000 
                 2 2009-02-27 01:05:05     87  103 7.00000 3.75900 
                 3 2009-02-27 02:05:05     87  103 6.40039 3.43701 
                 4 2009-02-28 02:10:05     87  103 4.79883 2.57697 
                 5 2009-02-28 04:05:05     87  103 4.10156 2.20254 
                 6 2009-02-28 05:05:05     87  103 2.59961 1.39599
                 7 2009-03-01 03:20:05     87  103 2.59961 1.39599", 
                 header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dat$date_time = as.POSIXct(paste0(dat$date_time, dat$time), tz="UTC")
dat = dat %>% select(-time)
```

**2. Helper function to convert hms time strings to seconds since midnight**

```
hms_to_numeric = function(x) {
  x = as.POSIXct(paste("2010-01-01", x))
  3600 * hour(x) + 60 * minute(x) + second(x)
}
```

**3. Filter the data to include only rows within the time range**

```
dat %>% 
  filter(between(as.numeric(date_time) - as.numeric(as.POSIXct(substr(date_time,1,10), tz="UTC")), 
                 hms_to_numeric("02:05:00"), 
                 hms_to_numeric("03:30:00")))
```

> ```
>             date_time loc_id node  energy   kgco2
> 1 2009-02-27 02:05:05     87  103 6.40039 3.43701
> 2 2009-02-28 02:10:05     87  103 4.79883 2.57697
> 3 2009-03-01 03:20:05     87  103 2.59961 1.39599
> ```