Subsetting a custom time range in base R
I need to get the list of temperatures from a weather station from 9am to 9am the next day in R and set their dates to the second day. A simplified version of the data looks like



DateTime
Temp




2024-05-06 08:23:01
12


2024-05-06 09:27:01
10


2024-05-06 12:53:31
5


2024-05-07 01:28:16
30


2024-05-07 05:07:59
30


2024-05-07 09:36:48
9



I would like to produce a dataframe of only the 9am:9am values so that



DateTime
Temp




2024-05-07
10


2024-05-07
5


2024-05-07
30


2024-05-07
30



My function to do this is
subnine=function(esheet){
 mydates<-unique(as.Date(esheet$DateTime))
 sheet9<-esheet[0,]
 esheet$DateTime<-as.POSIXlt(esheet$DateTime)
 for (l in 2:length(mydates))
{ 
   dateslice<-subset(esheet,(as.Date(esheet$DateTime)==mydates[l-1]&esheet$DateTime$hour>=9)|(as.Date(esheet$DateTime)==mydates[l] & esheet$Datetime$hour<9))
   dateslice$DateTime<-mydates[l]+1
  sheet9<-rbind(sheet9,dateslice)
 }
return(sheet9)
}

It is returning only the pre 9am values for the second day, so



DateTime
Temp




2024-05-07
30


2024-05-07
30



What is preventing the first part of the or(|) statement in my subset from selecting the first day's post 9am values? The logical statement works outside of the function/loop.

It would be easier to help if you could edit your question to include sample data as code. One way to do this would be to run dput(head(esheet)) and paste the output into the question.

Does something like this question cover it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44251952/496803 ?

Might it be simpler to set the date using the datetime + 15 hours?

First, make sure that DateTime is formatted appropriately to "POSIXt" format. We can do this using as.POSIXct where we set our time zone. Best, we save the time zone in an string, we will use it two times.
> my_tz <- "CET"  ## adjust this to your requirements!
> df$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(as.character(df$DateTime), tz=my_tz)  ##*

I use as.character here to prevent an accidentally entered time zone from changing the times.
Next, we generate the first changeover to 0900 AM,
> (chg1 <- as.POSIXct(paste(as.Date(df$DateTime)[1], "09:00:00"), tz=my_tz))
[1] "2024-05-06 09:00:00 CEST"

which we will use to create a sequence of changeovers.
> (dsq <- seq.POSIXt(chg1 - 60^2*24, by='1 day', 
+                   length.out=length(unique(as.Date(df$DateTime))) + 2L))
 [1] "2024-05-05 09:00:00 CEST" "2024-05-06 09:00:00 CEST" "2024-05-07 09:00:00 CEST"
 [4] "2024-05-08 09:00:00 CEST" "2024-05-09 09:00:00 CEST" "2024-05-10 09:00:00 CEST"
 [7] "2024-05-11 09:00:00 CEST" "2024-05-12 09:00:00 CEST" "2024-05-13 09:00:00 CEST"
[10] "2024-05-14 09:00:00 CEST"

"POSIXt" format stores the time internally as seconds since "1970-01-01 00:00:00" aka "unix epoch". So if we subtract 60^2*24, the number of seconds of a day, we get a day earlier.  cut.POSIXt which we will use in the final step needs a lower and an upper bound, so we add one element at each end.
Finally we use the changeovers as breaks= to cut the DateTimes into Dates.
> transform(df, date=as.Date(as.character(cut.POSIXt(DateTime, breaks=dsq))))
              DateTime Temp       date
1  2024-05-06 08:23:01   12 2024-05-05
2  2024-05-06 09:27:01   10 2024-05-06
3  2024-05-06 12:53:31    5 2024-05-06
4  2024-05-07 01:28:16   30 2024-05-06
5  2024-05-07 05:07:59   30 2024-05-06
6  2024-05-07 09:36:48    9 2024-05-07
7  2024-05-08 08:23:01   11 2024-05-07
8  2024-05-08 10:27:01   12 2024-05-08
9  2024-05-08 12:53:31    6 2024-05-08
10 2024-05-09 01:28:16   31 2024-05-08
11 2024-05-09 05:09:59   32 2024-05-08
12 2024-05-09 11:36:48   10 2024-05-09
13 2024-05-10 08:23:01   11 2024-05-09
14 2024-05-10 10:27:01   12 2024-05-10
15 2024-05-10 12:53:31    6 2024-05-10
16 2024-05-12 01:28:16   31 2024-05-11
17 2024-05-12 05:09:59   32 2024-05-11
18 2024-05-12 09:36:48   10 2024-05-12
19 2024-05-13 01:28:16   10 2024-05-12
20 2024-05-13 05:09:59   11 2024-05-12
21 2024-05-13 11:36:48   12 2024-05-13


Data
> dput(df)
structure(list(DateTime = c("2024-05-06 08:23:01", "2024-05-06 09:27:01", 
"2024-05-06 12:53:31", "2024-05-07 01:28:16", "2024-05-07 05:07:59", 
"2024-05-07 09:36:48", "2024-05-08 08:23:01", "2024-05-08 10:27:01", 
"2024-05-08 12:53:31", "2024-05-09 01:28:16", "2024-05-09 05:09:59", 
"2024-05-09 11:36:48", "2024-05-10 08:23:01", "2024-05-10 10:27:01", 
"2024-05-10 12:53:31", "2024-05-12 01:28:16", "2024-05-12 05:09:59", 
"2024-05-12 09:36:48", "2024-05-13 01:28:16", "2024-05-13 05:09:59", 
"2024-05-13 11:36:48"), Temp = c(12L, 10L, 5L, 30L, 30L, 9L, 
11L, 12L, 6L, 31L, 32L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 6L, 31L, 32L, 10L, 10L, 
11L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))


How could I run this for a dataset with multiple days?

@Nadka We will use cut for this. Please see updated answer.

Thank you. I was able to adapt this for my uses by removing things from before 9AM for the first day and adding 1 day at the end

The actual source of the problem ended up being my data type conversion. The time was not being included in the conversion for large datasets. I defined the format with  esheet$DateTime<-as.POSIXlt(esheet$DateTime,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") and my subsetting worked within the loop.
